# Suzuki swift VVT oil sensor leak oil into belts and alternator

Tags: suzuki, swift

Suzuki swift  VVT oil sensor leak oil into belts and alternator. What kind of issue will cause this oil leak from vvt sensor. Big help

Answer (score 1):

Oil into belts etc reduces the life of the belts and makes a mess, also can get onto the ground adding to pollution.

This should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The VVT sensor has seals to prevent oil leakage. The seals need to be changed. It could eventually cause your VVT sensor to fail causing performance problems and check engine light. Your belts will deteriorate and slip. After you repair leak, I would change the affected belts.